# Cannot find module '@ioc:Adonis/Core/HttpContext' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: adonis.js

I installed adonis core for building my SDK for adonisjs but I get

```
Cannot find module '@ioc:Adonis/Core/HttpContext' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

I'm not building an adonis server I want to create and SDK for adonjis

version

```
"@adonisjs/core": "^5.9.0"
```